# jsp not showing spring validator errors

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am creating a project using spring MVC.
I am validating fields using jsr303.
It is working fine It showing errors of fields in console but not in jsp page
Can any one let me know what wrong I am doing here ?

My controller method is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addCampaign", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute(value="Campaign") @Valid CampaignEntity campaignObj,BindingResult result, ModelMap model, Principal principal) {

        validator.validate(campaignObj, result);

        if(result.hasErrors()){         

            System.out.println(result.getErrorCount());
            System.out.println(result.toString());

            CampaignEntity campaignBean = new CampaignEntity();

            Map<String,String> agencies = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
            agencies.put("1", "United Stated");
            agencies.put("2", "China");
            agencies.put("3", "Singapore");
            agencies.put("4", "Malaysia");

            model.addAttribute("agencies", agencies);
            model.addAttribute("publishers", agencies);
            model.addAttribute("Campaign", campaignBean);

            return "addCampaign";   
        }else{
            return campaign(model, principal);
        }
    }
```

In jsp I am showing error using tag

```
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="error" />
```

my entity class is

```
package com.nativeunlock.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = CampaignEntity.GET_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY,
            query = "from CampaignEntity campaign"
    ),
    @NamedQuery(
            name = CampaignEntity.DELETE_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY,
            query = "DELETE FROM CampaignEntity campaign WHERE campaign.campaign_id = :campaign_id"
    )    
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign")
public class CampaignEntity implements Serializable {

    public static final String GET_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY ="getCampaignList";
    public static final String DELETE_CAMPAIGNS_QUERY ="deleteCampaignList";

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "campaign_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int campaign_id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message="Name field is mandatory.")
    private String name;


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "no_of_views")
    @NotNull(message="No. of Views field is mandatory.")
    private int no_of_views;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "video_url") 
    @NotEmpty(message="Video URL field is mandatory.")
    private String video_url;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "start_date")    
    @NotEmpty(message="Start Date field is mandatory.")
    private String  start_date;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    @NotEmpty(message="End Date field is mandatory.")
    private String end_date;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "click_to_play")
    @NotNull(message="Click to play field is mandatory.")
    private int click_to_play;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "frequency")
    @NotNull(message="Frequency field is mandatory.")
    private int frequency;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "priority")
    @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 100)
    @NotNull(message="Priority field is mandatory.")
    private int priority;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "divice")
    @NotNull(message="Divice field is mandatory.")
    private int divice;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "operating_system")
    @NotNull(message="Operating system field is mandatory.")
    private int operating_system;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
    @NotEmpty(message="Publisher field is mandatory.")
    private PublisherEntity publishers;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agency_id")
    @NotEmpty(message="Agency field is mandatory.")
    private AgencyEntity agencies;

}
```

my validator class is

```
package com.nativeunlock.Validator;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.nativeunlock.dto.CampaignEntity;

@Component
public class CampaignValidator implements Validator{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class c) {
        return CampaignEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object command, Errors errors) {
        CampaignEntity campaignBean = (CampaignEntity)command;
        /*if(!regBean.getPassword().equals(regBean.getRePassword()))
            errors.rejectValue("rePassword","password.notmatch");*/
    }

}
```

Comment: setting a breakpoint on ErrorsTag (its methods and methods inherited from base classes) might help

Comment: @JohnDonn : Can you please let me know how can I set Break point, I am getting errors in controller , I have print them in console

Comment: if you are working with Eclipse, you should press Ctrl+Shift+T and type the name of the class ErrorsTag; if you have the sources, you will see the class source get opened. If not, you have to find your spring-mvc jar and associate to it the source code you download from the web. As soon as the source opens you may set breakpoints in exactly the same way you do it with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by adding a model attribute `model.addAttribute("Campaign", campaignBean);` you're removing your binding errors from the model.

Binding errors are bound to the validated instance. If you set a breakpoint to a first line inside your method and inspect a model, you will see a validated object with the key `Campaign`, but also a binding error object with the key `org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.Campaign`

When you move further, and reach a point where you're adding a new instance to the model under a 'Campaign' key, notice that the binding errors will get removed from the model, since the instance they're bound is no longer existing, and that is why you don't see them in your JSP.

Remove the `model.addAttribute("Campaign", campaignBean);` or change the key, and you should see your binding erros.

Also not that you don't need the manual invocation `validator.validate(campaignObj, result);` the *@Valid* will call the validation for you